# How to synchronize adds and modifications with another a local folder on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, synchronization, version-control, versioning

I am looking for a solution to mirror a folder at every change by synchronizing it with another local folder (let's say C:\Data and C:\Mirror) : synchronize new files and modifications but do not synchronize suppressions.

I know this is possible with rsync (synchronize everything but suppressions), but I firstly would like to know if there is any built-in feature for that ?

Secondly, I saw it is possible to trigger tasks on events in the task scheduler, so is it possible to trigger this synchronization task when any change happens in the folder ?

The built-in versioning tool is not enough accurate (it only makes saves at 7:00 and 12:00).

The goal is to be able to avoid files suppressions mistakes on the server. If someone deletes a folder, he is able to recover it from the read-only folder where suppressions are not synchronized.

Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a suppresion?

You might look into Robocopy and see if it fits your needs.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd

Comment: Excellent, I never heard about robocopy before, it correctly synchronizes my changes without deleting files when the mirror option is disabled. Any idea now of how to trigger it at any folder change ?

Comment: Glad to help. Robocopy has a monitor option (/mon:<N>). I've never used it but it should do the trick.